# Standardization (z-score) across the “Samples” or across the “variables”?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, data-mining, normalization, computational-statistics, standardization

I found in literature that one of the most common way of standardization data is to compute z-scores (mean subtraction and division by standard deviation). Can anybody tell me if it is ok to compute z-scores for each sample instead of each variable?

I have a data set of 12x200 (12 Subjects and 200 Attributes) where all the variables/attributes are measured on the same unit but do have different ranges. Literature says, z-score has to be computed for each attribute (i.e, standardizing each column). My question is what if I standardize subjects (i.e, standardizing each row)? Is that acceptable from statistical point of view?

Basically I am training an SVM classier. I got 75% classification accuracy on raw data, 83% on column standardization (z-score of each individual attribute across all samples) and 100% with row standardization (z-score of individual samples).

I would like to go with standardizing each subject instead of attribute as it gives me better classification accuracy. Also, in case if I have just 1 subject for independent testing of my SVM classifier, I can do that by standardization it this way. In other case, if I train SVM with attribute standardization than I can not perform independent testing while having just 1 subject (because I can not z-score attributes of 1 subject independently). I need advice if this is something viable in statistics?

Comment: How to you perform model selection and performance estimation?

Comment: I have two data sets both of (12x200). I used first data set for building (training) the SVM classifier and the second data set for independent testing of the trained SVM classifier. Both data sets are standardized separately. Performance is measured as a fraction of correctly classified samples.

Comment: How can you get "almost 100%" accuracy with only 12 subjects? The maximum accuracy below 100% on a dataset of 12 subjects is 92%.

Comment: I worry that 24 subjects is too small to do any model tuning on. Your validation is going to be far too noisy and you're likely to overfit. At the very least you should be using cross-validation rather than a single test-train split.

Comment: Thanks Ben for your comment. You are right, I gave rough estimate of the accuracy percentage. I should have mentioned the actual values. The actual classification accuracy is (9 out of 12 = 75%), (10 out of 12 = 83.33%) and (12 out of 12 = 100%).

Comment: 24 subjects are considered far too many in gene expression data sets. Unfortunately, we have to cope with scarcity of samples in this field. I trained my SVM on 12 subjects and performed leave one out cross validation and later performed independent testing on other 12 subjects.